# Use button click to change child view

Tags: laravel-5

I have a button on my main layout page:

```
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" id="run" onclick="" VALUE="Run File Finish"  class="button" style.visibility="visible">
```

All I want to do is redirect to a separate child view when the button is clicked. Simple enough right? No, all I can find after searching for hours are suggestions to use an href. I am not using bootstrap and do not want to use an href. Since this seems to be to be a common thing to do in web design, I can't beleive there is not a simple way to do this. I am finding the documentation on laravel 5 less than adequate. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not fully clear, although i understood that u want to bring a child view in focus on click of a button.

So, you can bring child view into focus by using scrollTop()

```
$(window).scrollTop($('.footer').position().top);
```

above line will calculate position of child view (in this case child view with class footer) from top of the page and then scoll the page to bring the child view in view, put that line in a javascript function and call it onclick of button.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks. Let you know.

Comment: <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" id="run" onclick="getIssues()" VALUE="Run File Finish"  class="button" style.visibility="visible">

Comment: Here's my function:

Comment: function getIssues(){
 $(window).scrollTop($('partials.rightside').position().top);
};

Comment: I'm pretty new at this, so it is probably me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally had to use hrefs to fix problem. Not a great solution.